# Car parking special-relavity puzzle

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames

Hi I read the following puzzle from an old text book long time ago. However it doesn't provide the answer. So what is the solution?

Let's suppose a car is going to park to a garage and the garage is exactly the same size of the the static size of the car. Now the car is running in a speed that in its point of view the garage is just 1/10 of its static size. So it will consider the garage is too small to fit. On the other hand, the garage manager consider the car is only 1/10 of the garage size so it definitely fit.

The question is to explain what will ACTUALLY happen if the car try to park in the garage, and what the garage manager and the driver will see.

Comment: This is more commonly known as the ladder or barn-pole paradox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox

Comment: This is a very famous "paradox" in special relativity; this is a pretty good discussion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox

Comment: @MichaelBrown :)

Comment: @joshphysics Within a minute of each other. Again! :P

Comment: Thanks a lot for given the wikipedia reference. I learn a lot.

Comment: As the driver slows down to park, the size of the barn appears to expand from the drivers perspective to match the shape of the car.